# Tentando entender o print do Java

Tags: java, string, tipagem, concatenação-de-string

Observem o código logo abaixo;

```
public class Dois {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 3;
        int b = 4;

        System.out.print(" " + 7 + 2 + " ");

    }

}
```

O resultado é 72, mas eu achava que era para o resultado ser 7 + 2 que daria 9.

Porque ele imprimiu 72? Ele está seguindo alguma regra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque o `+` ocorre logo após uma *string*, o `" "`, então o objeto ali é do tipo *string*. Operadores são sobrecarregados (em Java isso é meio uma gambiarra, mas ainda assim ele é), portanto em cada tipo de dado, o operador pode executar uma coisa diferente. Você não pode definir suas próprias sobrecargas, mas os tipos chamados primitivos do Java já possuem uma pronta. O `+` quando encontra uma `string` é uma operação de concatenação, então ele junta todos os textos e não faz somas.

Para juntar, nesse caso, Java resolveu que seria de tipagem fraca e fazer uma coerção automática para `string` porque a expressão inicial era `string`. Então `" " + 7` dá `" 7"`, aí `" 7" + 2` dá `" 72"` e finalmente `" 72" + " "` dá `" 72 "`.

Então é isso, sobrecarga mais tipagem fraca parcial fizeram Java dar esse resultado que parece esquisito, mas tem algum sentido, ainda que seja uma regra questionável.

Answer (score 0):

É só colocar parenteses em volta da operação e o java vai efetuar a operação em vez de os cancatenar.

```
public class testes {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = 3;
        int b = 4;

        System.out.print(" " + (7 + 2) + " ");
    }
}
```